# How to Use the Sample Application in IBM MQ Light

Tags: java, ibm-mq, amqp

I am trying to send the message as well as receive the message to IBM MQ lite, I Extracted the `mqlight-developer-1.0.2.0-L151130.2` and `mqlight-distribution-1.0.2016020300` on c drive. I also Downloaded the required jar
    Google Gson 2.2.4, 
    Logback 1.1.2, 
    Apache Netty 4.0.21.Final, 
    Stateless4J 2.5.0, 
    SLF4J 1.7.5
    Commons SSL 0.3.11
    com.ibm.mqlight

I started the Mq Light and UI is Appeared ,
To run the helloWorld program I getting some difficulty. How can i do that

Comment: Please provide more info about the difficulty you are having. What error are you seeing?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code it will push the message in IBM MQ lite

```
package com.Queue;
import com.ibm.mqlight.api.ClientOptions;

import com.ibm.mqlight.api.Delivery;
import com.ibm.mqlight.api.DestinationAdapter;
import com.ibm.mqlight.api.NonBlockingClient;
import com.ibm.mqlight.api.NonBlockingClientAdapter;
import com.ibm.mqlight.api.StringDelivery;


public class SendReceive2 
{
    public static void main(String[] cmdline) 
    {
        ClientOptions clientOpts = ClientOptions.builder().setCredentials("ad", "jms123").build();



        NonBlockingClient.create("amqp://localhost", clientOpts, new NonBlockingClientAdapter<Void>()
        {

            public void onStarted(NonBlockingClient client, Void context) 
            {
                client.subscribe("JmsQueue",  new DestinationAdapter<Void>() 
                {
                    public void onMessage(NonBlockingClient client, Void context, Delivery delivery) 
                    {
                        if (delivery.getType() == Delivery.Type.STRING)
                            System.out.println(((StringDelivery)delivery).getData());
                    }
                }, null, null);
            }
        }, null);





        NonBlockingClient.create("amqp://localhost", clientOpts, new NonBlockingClientAdapter<Void>()
        {
            public void onStarted(NonBlockingClient client, Void context) 
            {
                client.send("JmsQueue", "Jms Queue is Formed!", null);
            }

        }, null);






    }//main


}//class
```